# Can I make a game in Xcode 6 Beta 7 then move your game project till the official release?

Tags: ios, xcode

Ok I Just want to ask. If I work on a Game on xcode 6 beta 7 and then when the official release of xcode 6 comes out can I move the game that I worked on the beta version and work on the official release. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is most likely yes, though only Apple can give you this answer with certainty. The final release of XCode 6 is expected to arrive soon, and it is unlikely that Apple would make any major incompatible changes to it's project file format now. Which means that a project created with the Beta versions should open just fine with the final release version.

You could be on more dangerous grounds if you plan to use Swift for making your game though. Swift has still not been finalized, and Apple is actively working on making changes to the language as well as fixing compiler bugs. Therefore, it is possible that the final version of XCode 6 could contain some incompatible changes in the language. Which would mean that you might run into compilations issues when you move to the release version.

Personally, I would not wait for the release version to get started on a project. At this late stage in the release cycle, I'd expect incompatible changes to be few and mostly small enough that they should be easy to fix.